# How to store data in Firebase Real-time Database under different date

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I am making an App to save and display the seizure history of patients. As I am new to Flutter, I am having difficulty in how to store data in firebase for the current user at the time of seizure occurrence.

I am storing data in the `real-time database`, so for that, I am using the date as a child and if more than 1-time seizure has occurred then it will store the data with the new key under the same date, but let say if a seizure occurs tomorrow as well with date 3-6-2021, then how will it store the value with a new date?

Currently, data is storing like this:

[image]

How can I store data with the new date under the same child as Seizure_history?

My code looks like this:

```
// Store seizure data to firebase on occurrence
  storeSeizureData() {
    String dateString = DateTime.now().toString();
    var dateTime = DateTime.parse(dateString);
    var date = "${dateTime.day}-${dateTime.month}-${dateTime.year}";
    String duration = '15';
    print("Saving data to firebase");
    ref
        .child('User_data')
        .child(cuser.uid)
        .child("Seizure_history")
        .child(date)
        .push()
        .set({'duration': duration, 'datetime': dateString});

    Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) {
          return Homepage(device: widget.device);
        },
      ),
      (route) => false,
    );
  }
```

I want that next day seizure should be stored separately with the new date and not under the previous date, i want to store like this:

```
{
  "User_data" : {
    "QURxPw4UwBhvn0ZdMYb1wNPJ9ZH2" : {
      "Seizure_history" : {
        "2-6-2021" : {
          "-Mb8E79qdLq2-EI3Vy0i" : {
            "datetime" : "2021-06-02 01:20:56.535240",
            "duration" : "15"
          },
          "-Mb8EA3TYOQOUVpzQ3aE" : {
            "datetime" : "2021-06-02 01:21:08.509808",
            "duration" : "15"
          }
        }
        "3-6-2021" : {
          "-Mb8E79qdLq2-EI3Vy0i" : {
            "datetime" : "2021-06-02 01:20:56.535240",
            "duration" : "15"
          },
          "-Mb8EA3TYOQOUVpzQ3aE" : {
            "datetime" : "2021-06-02 01:21:08.509808",
            "duration" : "15"
          }
        }
      },
      "caregivers" : {
        "-Mat_n4SPyg3mgAFJeYi" : {
          "Caregiver_Name" : "Bro ",
          "Caregiver_Number" : "033-253-04108 "
        }
      },
      "dateBirth" : "1999-05-26",
      "email" : "nabia.salman99@gmail.com",
      "gender" : "female",
      "mobile_no" : "2o29238347",
      "name" : "Nabia Salman",
      "profile_photo" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/epicare-4d900.appspot.com/o/image_picker5066472271726518955.jpg?alt=media&token=41b83fa6-4429-448d-8b1b-48549efacba8"
    },
    "SmnClTT1STO3HywzhfZed1EF8GC2" : {
      "caregivers" : {
        "-MaXrew6oMLNIbpLdL9r" : {
          "Caregiver_Name" : "Dad",
          "Caregiver_Number" : "03145107020 "
        },
        "-MaXrhdR3BB4CVm_cRMN" : {
          "Caregiver_Name" : "Mom",
          "Caregiver_Number" : "03145308797 "
        },
        "-MaXtqrOMw0QLGdKkndG" : {
          "Caregiver_Name" : "Sister Zong",
          "Caregiver_Number" : "03176037020 "
        }
      },
      "dateBirth" : "2021-05-12",
      "email" : "hania9@gmail.com",
      "gender" : "leamef",
      "mobile_no" : "875487248944",
      "name" : "Hania Salman",
      "profile_photo" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/epicare-4d900.appspot.com/o/c76d8746-395c-4632-82c3-709a8439f6c76494573163837145403.jpg?alt=media&token=0b425643-0e53-433b-aa19-a61898b4265f"
    },
    "yh6ATxquKjbmIWTbhVBudrGBVKB3" : {
      "caregivers" : {
        "-MaUwABpcS_MD6OLmaLP" : {
          "Caregiver_Name" : "Dad",
          "Caregiver_Number" : "03145107020 "
        }
      },
      "dateBirth" : "2021-05-21",
      "email" : "abdurehmanq19@gmail.com",
      "gender" : "male",
      "mobile_no" : "03325304108",
      "name" : "Abdurehman",
      "profile_photo" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/epicare-4d900.appspot.com/o/image_picker-2053800923.jpg?alt=media&token=8232ffd0-bbb7-4090-99f6-10526d0de292"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks correct, tomorrow will be a different day, so the child will be 3-6-2021, will create another node and store there.

Comment: Actually, i just wrote this code, so I thought the next date's data will appear under the previous date

Comment: It will store on the next date. You can try by setting the date variable with a different value, for example: var date = '3-6-2021'

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what result you want to get. Can you export the data as JSON text, and then add to your question how you *want* it to be stored? You can get the JSON as text by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: If i am got correctly, the code is correct. It will save each day in a different node under Seizure_history.

Comment: let me check it with a new date by hard coding the date

Comment: Thanks for the update Nabia. I'm still not sure I understand though. Since your code takes the date from `DateTime.now()`, it should already save it based on the current day (so that values with `"datetime" : "2021-06-03 ..."` will be stored under a key `"3-6-2021"`. Is that not happening for you?

Comment: Actually, i wanna know if the code that i have provided is going to save the next day under the previous day, or will it make another node for the next date? like it has created for 2-6-2021.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you start with:

```
String dateString = DateTime.now().toString();
```

Any time this code runs, it determines the current date. So if you run the code on June 3, it will generate that date, and the key in your database will be for June 3.

---

Unrelated to your actual question, but I **strongly** recommend using ISO-8601 format for the dates, which would be: `"2021-06-02"`. The advantage of this format, is that you can query for date ranges, for example getting all dates in 2021 with `ref.orderByKey().startAt("2021-").endAt("2021~")`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I'll keep that in mind for future :)